# Dataset doesn't fit in memory for LSTM training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to create model that is trained on large music dataset. The midi files are converted into numpy arrays. Since LSTM requires sequential data, the dataset size becomes so huge on converting into a sequence for the LSTM.

I convert the midi notes into index based on the keynote and duration, so I get 6 classes for C4 key. Likewise I get C3 to B5 so totally 288 classes along with classes for rest periods.

The converted format of a single midi looks like this.

`midi = [0,23,54,180,23,45,34,.....];`

For training the LSTM, the x and y becomes

`x = [[0,23,54..45],[23,54,..,34],...];`

`y=[[34],[76],...]`

The values in x and y are further transformed into one-hot encodings.
Hence the size of the data becomes huge for just 60 small mid files, but I have 1700 files. How can I train the model with this amount of files. I checked ImageGenerator but it requires data to be in separate class directories. How to achieve this?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using one-hot encoding?

Comment: No specific reason, is it possible to train just with                    
```x = [[0,23,54..45],[23,54,..,34],...];```
```y=[[34],[76],...]```. Instead of converting it into one-hot encoding?

Comment: one-hot encoding is to convert text data in to numerical forms, so ML model can use it. If you dataset is already in numerical form there's no need to use one-hot encoding.
Another thing one-hot encoding uses huge amount of memory if there are lots of unique words in dataset, if possible use TF-IDF or Word2Vec transformation.

Comment: If I use one-hot encoding the training takes increased amount of time and validation loss is high. Why is this?

Comment: Training time increases as amount of data increases(representation size grows in one-hot encoding compare to other transformation). LSTM model is sequential one, it's prediction depends on the previous sequence of the data, so I suspect with one-hot encoding you might get sequence of long ZEROs which is creating this problem.

Comment: Embedding layer added model takes much time in training a epoch than directly feeding it with one hot encoded input model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a generator class for this problem used the following code. The generator is modified for my purpose. Memory usage is dramatically reduced.

```
class Generator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size=4):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set

        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.indices = np.arange(len(self.x))

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        inds = self.indices[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_x = []
        batch_y = []
        for ind in inds:
            ip = []

            for q in self.x[ind]:
                o = np.zeros(323)
                o[int(q)] = 1
                ip.append(o)
            batch_x.append(ip)
            hot_encoded = []
            for val in self.y[ind]:

                t = np.zeros(323)
                t[int(val)] = 1
                hot_encoded.append(t)
            batch_y.append(hot_encoded)

        return np.array(batch_x), np.array(batch_y)

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        # np.random.shuffle(self.indices)
        np.random.shuffle(self.indices)
```

Answer (score 6):

You should generate you training data on the fly, during the training itself. 
Based on [tf documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit), you can write your own generator to use as training data, or inheritate from [Sequence](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence).

The first option should look like

```
def create_data_generator(your_files):
    raw_midi_data = process_files(your_files)
    seq_size = 32

    def _my_generator():
        i = 0 
        while True:
            x = raw_midi_data[i:i + seq_size]
            y = raw_midi_data[i + seq_size]
            i = (i + 1) % (len(raw_midi_data) - seq_size)
            yield x, y

    return _my_generator()
```

And then call it with (assuming tf >= 2.0)

```
generator = create_data_generator(your_files)
model.fit(x=generator, ...)
```

If you are using "old" Keras (from before tensorflow 2.0) **which Keras team itself does not recommend**, you should use `fit_generator` instead:

```
model.fit_generator(generator, ...)
```

With this solution, you only store your data in memory once, there is no duplication due to overlapping sequences.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am implementing your answer, I will reply you soon.

Comment: is that model.fit_generator?@Théo Rubenach

Comment: Your solution doesn't work, it wants y in parameter.

Comment: Then I assume you're using "old" Keras (doc at https://keras.io/). I updated my answer for both version of Keras.

Comment: Thanks, I used sequence generator and it worked well.

Comment: I am developing a convLSTM, where I have about 500 GB of data. This does not fit into my memory availability, so I am trying to write a custom data loader based on your design above ("first option"). However, at least to my understanding, this loads in all of the data into memory, just in different batches. When I train my model based on the custom data generator design above, I still run out of memory since all of the data is loaded in. Is there a way to load data one at a time, so I won't run out of memory?

Comment: @Gerson Instead of loading the data during generator initialization, try loading it in the while loop. Thus you only have a small portion of your data loaded in memory at each moment, and it should work